# HTML: Vertical align div in div

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I would like to vertical center a div in another div, but I don't get it to work. The image div needs to be centered in the parent (black) div. I've already tried the

```
position: absolute;
```

fix, as well as the

```
display: table-cell;
```

but they both don't seem to work. The probleems seems to be my parent div being 100%.. Can anybody help me out? The example is here:

http://jsfiddle.net/mkGXx/

Comment: This should help you
http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/priklady/vertical-align-final-solution-en.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div style="display: table; height: 800px; #position: relative; overflow: hidden;">
    <div style=" #position: absolute; #top: 50%;display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;">
      <div class="greenBorder" style=" #position: relative; #top: -50%">
        any text<br />
        any content<br /><br /><br />
        everything is vertically centered
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

see at: http://jsfiddle.net/9eDXM/

Comment: You have posted the same link as above, `update` the code in jsfiddle & post the link.

Comment: As you can see in my example, I've got a 100% height div. When using this, your solution doesn't work, unfortunately :(

Comment: your body has to be a height of 100% too